# CRM v2011 platform is not opening browsers other than IE

Tags: browser, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

When we're trying to open CRM portal v2011 with chrome or edge but aren't seeing anything, we are seeing just an empty page. But we try to open with IE, portal is working, main page is opening.

Also an extra information we installed update roll 6 last.

What can we do for open to browser other than IE?

Comment: CRM 2011 is not supported anymore

Comment: So what do you suggest us to do? In june, also explorer won't support anymore.

Comment: upgrade to a supported version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a more recent rollup to get CRM 2011 working with later browsers, this depends on the combination of the operating system as well.

> Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update Rollup 12 introduced additional
> browser compatibility for the Firefox, Chrome, and Safari web
> browsers.
>
> Important Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update Rollup 17 introduced
> compatibility with Internet Explorer 11 when it runs in Windows 7,> Windows 8.1 or Windows 10.

[Browser compatibility with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/browser-compatibility-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-861345c8-0c30-e630-beb7-8d8eb93b3f43)